# Android open .docx file via ContentResolver in QuickOffice crashes

Tags: android, android-intent, ms-word, android-contentprovider, document

For some reason my code for opening any downloaded file, and in this instance .docx does not work for QuickOffice, the exception I'm getting is this:

06-02 22:04:05.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 22:04:05.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2889): Process: com.quickoffice.android, PID: 2889
06-02 22:04:05.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2889): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 22:04:05.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at com.google.android.apps.docs.quickoffice.a.g.a(AbstractSaveAction.java:14)
06-02 22:04:05.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.menu.d.a(AbstractMenuItemController.java:28)
06-02 22:04:05.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.menu.c.a(AbstractButtonMenuItemController.java:24)
06-02 22:04:05.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.menu.y.a(MenuController.java:59)
06-02 22:04:05.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.menu.y.a(MenuController.java:59)
06-02 22:04:05.356: E/AndroidRuntime(2889):     at com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.menu.z.run(MenuController.java:37)

My code for establishing the intent is:

```
Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String mimeType = getMimeType(tempFile);

Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.companyname/"+ fileName);
install.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(install, "Open File");  
_progressDialog.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

My content provider code is as is:

```
    public class DownloadedFileContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

        @Override
        public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File privateFile = new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), uri.getPath());
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(privateFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
        }

           //Other overridden methods that return false and null for the ContentProvider class.
     }
```

I'm out of ideas, this is also the case for Microsoft Office on android, the document doesn't open at all. Office Suite is the only application opens everything.

Comment: You might try [using `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) instead of rolling your own, and see if that works better.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like below

```
            File file = new File(filePath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String fileExtension = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            fileExtension = fileExtension.toLowerCase();
            if(mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension) != null) {
                String type = mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);

                if(isTablet(activity))
                {
                    if(fileExtension.equals("txt"))
                    {
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/plain");    //changed from Uri.parse(fp, type) method
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
                }                   

                try{
                    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_AUTHENTICATION_COMPLETED);
                }catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    System.out.println("exception : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }                   
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The QuickOffice application crashes because it calls the `query` method of your ContentProvider. As this method is abstract, you must have implemented it in your custom ContentProvider, but probably with a null return or Exception throwing. As QuickOffice calls it when trying to use your content, it crashed (probably with a NullPointerException).

As CommonsWare suggests in his comment of the original post, you should use [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) instead. The Android doc is clear about how to use it. You don't need to use any Java code, everything is done in XML files (Manifest and path XML files).

I had the same problem. Using FileProvider made it work in an easiest and more secure way. Thank you CommonsWare.